# Oracle SQL Query for monthwise report

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys i have a table called **A** which has columns as

```
-----
  A
-----
S_DATE
DUR
VIEWS
AMOUNT
```

The data in the **table A**  has the following rows  which is **DateWise**.

```
20101023  12 1   10000.0 
20101101  2  4   200.0
20101114  4  5   -9
20101201  6  10  150.0 
20101219  1  12  130.0
```

My requirement is that i want to write an SQL query that does **monthwise** **report**. For example from webGUI , when i select on the dropdown for month as **DEC** and select year as **2010** . I need to create show the sum of DUR,VIEWS and AMOUNT from **1st of November 2010 to 1st of December 2010**.Any Ideas on how to do it.

The result for DEC2010 should be like below

```
**DEC2010 12 19 341**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would work (although of course due to your requirement the first day of november will be in both the november and december monthly reports ?!):

```
SQL> VARIABLE p_months VARCHAR2(3);
SQL> VARIABLE p_year NUMBER;
SQL> EXEC :p_months := 'DEC'; :p_year := 2010;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> WITH tableA AS (
  2  SELECT DATE '2010-10-23's_date , 12 dur, 1 views, 10000.0 amount FROM DUAL
  3  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2010-11-01',  2,  4 ,  200.0 FROM DUAL
  4  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2010-11-14',  4,  5 ,  -9    FROM DUAL
  5  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2010-12-01',  6,  10,  150.0 FROM DUAL
  6  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2010-12-19',  1,  12,  130.0 FROM DUAL
  7  )
  8  SELECT :p_months||:p_year month,
  9         SUM(dur),
 10         SUM(views),
 11         SUM(amount)
 12    FROM tableA
 13   WHERE s_date >= add_months(to_date(:p_months||:p_year, 'MONYYYY'), -1)
 14     AND s_date < to_date(:p_months||:p_year, 'MONYYYY') + 1;

MONTH        SUM(DUR) SUM(VIEWS) SUM(AMOUNT)
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
DEC2010            12         19         341
```